# Does the order of modules or CONFIG_* parameters matter in the Linux kernel config file?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am facing a kernel patching issue, where I have a set of patches that work for one person and not for me. Same git tree was used by both of us and it seems it might be the configuration used for kernel compilation that is causing this issue for me. Although I have asked for the .config file from the other developer, it might take time as he is a remote worker.

Meanwhile, I am trying to understand why the undefined references errors are seen in my case.

My question is, does the order of modules or CONFIG_* parameters matter in the config file? I am doubting that somewhere the order of kernel compilation is causing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been doing a lot of search but nothing is clearly mentioned about the order, maybe it is irrelevant.

Any tips to debug are most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, order of the parameters in the config file does not matter. But are if you absolutely sure you have the same initial code base and patches - try to `make clean`. Sometimes it helps.

Comment: I tried make clean, make mrproper etc. The problem was that one of the symbols was defined in a piece of code which was configured to be a module and another piece of code, being built as part of the kernel and not a module, required that.